# Does RSS tracks reserved or commited memory?

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm running experiments with different jvm options on java 8 in order to lower RSS:

- Script used for Rss tracking:

  `ps -o rss -o vsz -o pid $pid`
- JVM args for setting up java process:

  [`-XX:+PrintNMTStatistics -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html)
- Taking baseline with jcmd:

  `jcmd $pid VM.native_memory baseline`
- Taking diff with jcmd:

  `jcmd $pid VM.native_memory summary.diff`

Output (partial for Thread area):

```
-                    Thread (reserved=130696KB -21564KB, committed=130696KB -21564KB)
                            (thread #121 -21)
                            (stack: reserved=130048KB -21504KB, committed=130048KB -21504KB)
                            (malloc=379KB -67KB #610 -105)
                            (arena=268KB +7 #240 -42)
```

***Question***:
What memory will be taken into account for RSS from output above, is it `committed` or `reserved`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relation between reserved/committed and resident/virtual is a little more complex. RSS covers pages *resident* in physical memory. Things that have been paged out (or never paged in) can be committed memory but not resident.

Maybe this answers your question: reserved-but-not-committed pages cannot be resident.