# Java process memory issue

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a java process using jetty websockets. The process shows 151 live threads. The **top** result is showing 797MB of Resident memory.

[image]

Heap Memory used shows Committed as 231 MB

[image]

Non Heap Memory shows 115 MB.

[image]

There are total 1100 open file descriptors.

[image]

What I understand is every thread has a thread stack, say it is 1MB, then total memory used should be 151M + 231M + 115M + (file descriptors memory). 
Can someone tell me how all these lead to 797 MB of resident memory? What am I missing or not counting?

Comment: What are the resources managed by threads? Your count is 500Mb, your measure is 800Mb, difference is 300Mb, then 2Mb/thread or 280Kb/opened file. Well this is not surprising... There is a lot of small resources that you are not counting... You can use the flight recorder to examine precisely what happens.

Comment: They are normal jetty threads, processor threads doing small tasks. The files are the open websocket connections. I will check about flight recorder. What are the other small resources you meant, any reference/doc?

Comment: Your threads are executing code, then they necessarily use some data. Without code, impossible to answer. Use FR and you will see everything. What I mean is that what you think as too big is certainly not. Counting so roughly is not possible and having 30% error in your approximation is then normal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Huge system memory usage of java applications compared to heap usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223821/huge-system-memory-usage-of-java-applications-compared-to-heap-usage)