# Difference in Used, Committed and Max Heap Memory

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory-management, jvm, spark-streaming

I am monitoring a spark executor JVM of a OutOfMemoryException. I used Jconsole to connect to executor JVM. Following is the snapshot of Jconsole:
[image]

In the image used memory is shown as 3.8G and committed memory is 8.6G and Max memory is also 8.6G
Could anyone explain the difference between Used and Committed Memory or any link which explains it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a JVM report more committed memory than the linux process resident set size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173374/why-does-a-jvm-report-more-committed-memory-than-the-linux-process-resident-set)

Answer (score 50):

From the Java Doc of [`MemoryUsage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html),

***getUsed is:***

> the amount of used memory in bytes

***getCommitted()***

> Returns the amount of memory in bytes that is committed for  the Java
>   virtual machine to use.  This amount of memory is  guaranteed for the
>   Java virtual machine to use.

***getMax()***

> Returns the maximum amount of memory in bytes that can be used for
>   memory management.  This method returns -1 if the maximum memory size
>   is undefined.
>
> This amount of memory is not guaranteed to be available for memory
>   management if it is greater than the amount of committed memory.  The
>   Java virtual machine may fail to allocate memory even if the amount of
>   used memory does not exceed this maximum size.

Comment: what's the difference between committed and max memory (or rather, what's the point in having both)?

Comment: @dtc `committed` would start with `-Xms` ( and potentially grow ), while `max` would be the upper bound: `-Xmx`, for example. I guess `used` in this case would mean : resident + swapped pages.

Comment: So the difference between used and committed is that committed is guaranteed for the JVM to use? Does that mean used is not guaranteed to JVM to use? Sorry but this answer doesn't explain what's the difference.

Comment: @tolache it seems committed is guaranteed (might used in future), used is currently being used (so no future guarantee required, it's already consumed). For max, its allowed expansion provided memory is available when demanded.

Answer (score 35):

First `used < committed < max`,  and the unit of measure for all of them is **bytes**

- **init**: the initial amount of memory that the JVM requested from the operating system at startup.

  - this is controlled by the `-Xms` cli option of the java command. See [2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html)
- **used**: amount of memory that is actually in use, so the memory consumed by all objects including the objects that are not reachable but haven't been garbaged collected yet.

  - it can be lower than **init**
- **committed**: amount of memory that is reserved at the operating system level for the JVM process at the moment.

  - It can be equal or greater than the **used**, the JVM can request/allocated more memory from the OS and not really use it, but the OS is reserving that memory for the java process anyway.
  - it **can go down**, it maybe be even lower than **init** because the JVM can release memory back to the operating system.
  - if the JVM needs more memory, it will try to allocate more from the OS and then the **committed** will go up, but it's always possible that the OS runs of memory even if the amount of memory requested is lower that **max**
  - if you are trying to create new objects and the `used < committed` then the JVM does **not** need to request more memory from the OS and thus is **guaranteed** that it will succeed.
  - if you are trying to create new objects and the total amount of memory will go over `committed` then the JVM needs to allocate more memory from the OS before creating the object, that is **not guaranteed** to succeed (the OS may also run out of memory)
- **max**: the maximum amount of memory that the JVM will ever try to request / allocate from the operating system

  - controlled by the `-Xmx` cli options. See [2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html)
  - it is not guaranteed that the JVM will be able to allocate this much, the operating system may run out of memory because other processes reserved it.

So in the OP example

- **used** is 3.8G
- **committed** and **max** are 8.6G

that means that the JVM can allocate objects in the heap up to 8.6G and that is **guaranteed**, it won't have to ask the operating system for that since it was already allocated. If the JVM at some point requires more memory than that, because it needs to allocate more objects and it can't release any memory via garbage collection then it will fail with OOM since 8.6G is already the **max** it's allowed to request (I guess because it was started with `-Xmx8600M`.

Answer (score -2):

used memory is the amount of memory currently used in bytes while committed memory shows the amount of memory in bytes that is committed for JVM to use.