# What does 'heap total' mean in 'jcmd GC.heap_info output'?

Tags: java, jvm, java-17

Can some one let me know what does `heap total 3063808K` mean in the below output?

```
root@ip-10-210-3-44:/app# jcmd 34 GC.heap_info
34:
 garbage-first heap   total 3063808K, used 1095736K [0x0000000380000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  region size 16384K, 14 young (229376K), 6 survivors (98304K)
 Metaspace       used 396721K, committed 401984K, reserved 1400832K
  class space    used 48373K, committed 51328K, reserved 1048576K
```

Output of `jps -lvm`

```
root@ip-10-210-3-44:/app# jps -lvm
34 /app/spring-boot-application.jar -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75 -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+UseG1GC -Xlog:gc --add-modules=jdk.incubator.foreign --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.sql/java.sql=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dcontainer.id=
30533 jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jps.Jps -lvm -Dapplication.home=/opt/openjdk-17 -Xms8m -Djdk.module.main=jdk.jcmd
```

- Total container memory 24 GB

Java version

```
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

jmap output for heap is like below

```
root@ip-10-210-3-44:/app# jhsdb jmap --heap --pid 34
Attaching to process ID 34, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 17.0.5+8

using thread-local object allocation.
Garbage-First (G1) GC with 4 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 19327352832 (18432.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 1363144 (1.2999954223632812MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 11593056256 (11056.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 5452592 (5.1999969482421875MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 22020096 (21.0MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 16777216 (16.0MB)

Heap Usage:
G1 Heap:
   regions  = 1152
   capacity = 19327352832 (18432.0MB)
   used     = 1382900640 (1318.8368225097656MB)
   free     = 17944452192 (17113.163177490234MB)
   7.1551476915677386% used
G1 Young Generation:
Eden Space:
   regions  = 28
   capacity = 1677721600 (1600.0MB)
   used     = 469762048 (448.0MB)
   free     = 1207959552 (1152.0MB)
   28.0% used
Survivor Space:
   regions  = 1
   capacity = 16777216 (16.0MB)
   used     = 16777216 (16.0MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   100.0% used
G1 Old Generation:
   regions  = 57
   capacity = 1442840576 (1376.0MB)
   used     = 896361376 (854.8368225097656MB)
   free     = 546479200 (521.1631774902344MB)
   62.124769077744595% used
```

Comment: It means that the (current) total Java heap size is 3063808K bytes.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by 'current' total Java heap size? If you are referring current heap size then what is `used 1095736K` then?

Comment: 1)  Current == "right now", or "at this instant in time".  2) That is the amount of memory in the heap that is currently used; i.e. that holds objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple words, `total` is the current size of Java Heap, including used and free space.

More precisely, with G1 Garbage Collector, `total` is the space used by active [committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468670/difference-in-used-committed-and-max-heap-memory) heap regions.

G1 heap regions can be in one of 3 states:

- **Uncommitted:** it's just the reserved address space that does not occupy physical memory or swap.
- **Active:** the region is committed on the OS level and available for allocation.
- **Inactive:** a committed region that is no longer in use and can be uncommitted.

```
Reserved = Active + Inactive + Uncommitted
Committed = Active + Inactive
Available (or "total" in jcmd output) = Active
```