# Where do these java native memory allocated from?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, java-native-interface, pmap

JDK version is hotspot 8u_45

I researched native memory of my java process. The native memory even consumes more space than heap. However there are many native memory blocks which confuses me. The result of pmap -x for example:

```
00007f8128000000   65508   25204   25204 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f812bff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f812c000000   65508   24768   24768 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f812fff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8130000000   65508   25532   25532 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8133ff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8134000000   65524   22764   22764 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8137ffd000      12       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8138000000   65508   26456   26456 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f813bff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f813c000000   65508   23572   23572 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f813fff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8140000000   65520   23208   23208 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8143ffc000      16       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8144000000   65512   23164   23164 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8147ffa000      24       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8148000000   65516   23416   23416 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f814bffb000      20       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f814c000000   65508   23404   23404 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f814fff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8150000000   65512   24620   24620 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8153ffa000      24       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8154000000   65536   23976   23976 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8158000000   65508   23652   23652 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f815bff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f815c000000   65508   23164   23164 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f815fff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8160000000   65508   23344   23344 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8163ff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8164000000   65508   24052   24052 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8167ff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8168000000  131052   48608   48608 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f816fffb000      20       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8170000000   65516   23056   23056 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8173ffb000      20       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8174000000   65516   26860   26860 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8177ffb000      20       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8178000000   65508   23360   23360 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f817bff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f817c000000   65536   24856   24856 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8180000000   65512   23272   23272 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8183ffa000      24       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8184000000   65508   23688   23688 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8187ff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8188000000   65512   24024   24024 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f818bffa000      24       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f818c000000   65508   25020   25020 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f818fff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8190000000   65512   22868   22868 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8193ffa000      24       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8194000000   65508   24156   24156 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f8197ff9000      28       0       0 -----    [ anon ]
00007f8198000000   65508   23684   23684 rw---    [ anon ]
```

There are many blocks which occupy about 64M.

I use jcmd pid VM.native_memory detail to track these memory blocks. However, I cannot found these blocks with any of the memory ranges listed in the result of jcmd.

Furthermore, I noticed an article which mentions arena effect in malloc of glic [Java 8 and Virtual Memory on Linux](http://info.prelert.com/blog/java-8-and-virtual-memory-on-linux). However These blocks seem different from thread pool because 1. The mode is `rw---` not `-----` 2. The arena thread pool only affects virtual memory. It cannot explain these too much RSS.

I use gdb to track the allocated memory

```
dump binary memory mem.bin from to
```

mem.bin.1
[image]

mem.bin.2
[image]

mem.bin.3

[image]
mem.bin.4

[image]

There are about 30 blocks like those shown in the picture.

After some days, I use Google perf tools to track heap allocations. And found this:
[image]

It shows that: zip inflates consume nearly 2G memory. I guess it may concern with some compilation issue.

I have read this issue：https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8164293. Is this related to my concern?

So how can I track the source of these memory block?

Comment: What kind of Java process is this? Are you doing any interop?

Comment: @JornVernee This process is interop process of thrift and jetty

Comment: I mean native interop. That idea I had is that memory allocated outside of the VM will not show up through `jcmd`, but will show up with `pmap`.

Comment: @JornVernee Sorry I don't understand what is native interop. Can you please give me some example?

Comment: For instance when you call a function from a native `.so`/`.dll` from Java. I don't know those libraries well enough to say if they do that though.

Comment: That is a good point. I will track these down and reply to you. @JornVernee

Comment: you could try [NMT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31173374/1362755) to compare with pmap -x. Additionally look at a heap dump for direct byte buffers.

Comment: NMT is not enough. pmax -x shows many memory blocks outside ranges listed in NMT by jcmd @the8472

Comment: That is unrelated to compilation for sure. As I've told, ZipInputStream/JarInputStream is a quite common source of such leaks. E.g. an application calls `Class.getResourceAsStream` but does not close the result stream. Create a heap dump to see who holds `java.util.zip.Inflater` objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`jemalloc`](http://jemalloc.net/) or [`tcmalloc`](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) - they both have built-in allocation profiler that will help to identify the source of allocations.

Java process may use too much native memory for many reasons. Popular reasons are

- Direct ByteBuffers
- Memory allocated by `Unsafe.allocateMemory`
- Unclosed resources (e.g. `ZipInputStream`)
- other native libraries

Note that NativeMemoryTracking will not show memory consumed by native libraries.