# Incorrect native thread size

Tags: java, jvm

I run a test Java program on Windows machine.
When I run 200 threads I get this result:

```
Thread (reserved=223143KB, committed=223143KB)
   (thread #218)
   (stack: reserved=222208KB, committed=222208KB)
   (malloc=679KB #1293)
   (arena=255KB #435)
```

But my process really consumes only 27Mb. What does 'committed' means? Why it's much more than memory consumed by the process?

Comment: there is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173374/why-does-a-jvm-report-more-committed-memory-than-the-linux-process-resident-set)